# FullScreenContentCallback - onAdDismissedFullScreenContent never called

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using the newest ads play services (**21.4.0**) and see following behaviour (testing with test app id and test ad ids):

The `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent` function of `FullScreenContentCallback` is never called.

**Problem**

When I click the close button inside the interstitial ad no callback function is called... All other functions inside (at least the non error functions) are called successfully. Why? Am I missing something? I need to react to the event that the ad is being dismissed...

**Code**

1. load the ad

```kotlin
InterstitialAd.load(
    context,
    adId,
    AdRequest.Builder().build(),
    createInterstitialAdListener()
)
```

2. wait for the ad to be loaded inside the listener

```kotlin
private fun createInterstitialAdListener(): InterstitialAdLoadCallback {
    return object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdLoaded(ad: InterstitialAd) {
            super.onAdLoaded(ad)
            L.d { "Interstitial ad loaded..." }
            ad.fullScreenContentCallback = createFullScreenContentCallback("Interstitial")
            interstitialAd = ad
            this@AdsViewManager.onAdLoaded()
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(error)
            onAdLoadingError(error.message)
        }
    }
}

private fun createFullScreenContentCallback(type: String): FullScreenContentCallback {
    return object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
        override fun onAdClicked() {
            // works!
            L.d { "[$type] FullScreen ad clicked" }
        }

        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
            // never gets called!
            L.d { "[$type] FullScreen ad dismissed" }
            interstitialAd = null
            rewardedAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(error: AdError) {
            onAdLoadingError(error.message)
            interstitialAd = null
            rewardedAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdImpression() {
            // works!
            L.d { "[$type] FullScreen ad - IMPRESSION" }
        }

        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
            // works!
            L.d { "[$type] FullScreen ad showed..." }
        }
    }
}
```

3. show the ad when it is ready

```kotlin
fun show() {
  if (interstitialAd == null) {
   L.e { "Interstitial ad not ready" }
  } else {
    interstitialAd?.show(activity)
    L.d { "Showing interstitial ad..." }
  }
}
```

**Logs from code above**

```
Interstitial ad loaded...
Showing interstitial ad... 
[Interstitial] FullScreen ad showed... 
[Interstitial] FullScreen ad - IMPRESSION
// missing the close log... it never appears...
```

Comment: It is very difficult to reproduce the error

Comment: So what now? Is it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this manner, in your Activity

```
private var interstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    createInterstitialAdListener()
}
```

Your `loadAd` function

```
private fun createInterstitialAdListener(): InterstitialAdLoadCallback {
    return object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdLoaded(ad: InterstitialAd) {
            super.onAdLoaded(ad)
            L.d { "Interstitial ad loaded..." }
            interstitialAd = ad
            this@AdsViewManager.onAdLoaded()
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(error)
            onAdLoadingError(error.message)
        }
    }
}
```

While showing Ad, copy/paste following...

```
fun show() {
    if (interstitialAd == null) {
        L.e { "Interstitial ad not ready" }
    } else {
        interstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = fullScreenContentCallback
        interstitialAd?.show(activity)
        L.d { "Showing interstitial ad..." }
    }
}

private val fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
        override fun onAdClicked() {
            // works!
            L.d { "[$type] FullScreen ad clicked" }
        }

        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
            // never gets called!
            L.d { "[$type] FullScreen ad dismissed" }
            interstitialAd = null
            rewardedAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(error: AdError) {
            onAdLoadingError(error.message)
            interstitialAd = null
            rewardedAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdImpression() {
            // works!
            L.d { "[$type] FullScreen ad - IMPRESSION" }
        }

        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
            // works!
            L.d { "[$type] FullScreen ad showed..." }
        }
    }
}
```

It will work as expected. Let me know, if it didn't work